# File upload with Selenium WebDriver and FF24

Tags: java, firefox, file-upload, selenium, webdriver

I am facing an issue with the file upload with WebDriver, using Java, on Firefox 24.
And I can NOT use some external program like AutoIT or similar.

I have to upload a file to a section which's HTML code is:

```
<td>
<input type="file" name="file">
</td>
```

And what I was using in Eclipse is

```
pageObject.getTypeFileLocation().sendKeys(textFile);
pageObject.getUploadButton.click();
```

which does not work; also tried the first answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431978/file-upload-with-selenium-webdriver-and-java-one-solution) question but neither did the trick.

The test returns 'OK', but I suspected that nothing was being done so added a check to wait for 'Upload complete' text present; But the file is not uploaded, and timeouts after 20 seconds, even when the file to upload is 5KB and takes less than a second when manually uploaded.
 The `input=file` section contains a button and a 'No File Selected' text that changes to the filepath when a file is selected manually; and this is in what I am basing my idea that the file is not being upload; because the 'No File Selected' remains until the test fails.

I tried this on Chrome and seems to be working fine, and I know that there have been some reworks about `input=file` in FF since release 23, but mostly pointed to CSS styling, so I don't think it's related.

Also, a question that might sound kind of stupid, but questions are questions: Doesn't the `sendKeys()` action need a field to input those keys? I feel that the WebDriver is trying to write the path over a button, which can't perform the action as it's only a button.

Any help will be appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Comment: No.  `sendKeys()` does not need to be sent to a field, a button will work fine.  However, what you say about FF may be true...I currently use FF19 for automation...I would test seeing if a downgrade would make it work.

Comment: Check this link as well - http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_Does_WebDriver_support_file_uploads?

Comment: Still could not solve anything... thanks for the link, though!

Comment: Hi, Mariano. I had the same situation and manged to resolve it as I described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726005/how-to-click-on-input-type-file-across-browsers-using-selenium-webdriver/17496241#17496241 But again you will need to write AutoIT script. AFAIK, there is no way to handle native Windows pop-up using only WebDriver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it!

Don't know if it works for all browsers, but at least it does on FF and Chrome:

Found out that somebody used the FILE type, so reused it and got its absolute path:

```
protected File *fileName* = new File("*path to file*");
private String textFile = *fileName*.getAbsolutePath(); 
pageObject.getInput().sendKeys(textFile);
```

Hope somebody else finds it useful; as it's weird to be answering my own question.