# (Java) How to get xpath for upload window(just as openfiledialog) in selenium?

Tags: file, selenium, upload

I am testing automation with selenium and stuck here
When i click a button and a new popup window will open(just as OpenFileDialog) to select file from computer. I want to write a testcase for this step. Please help!!!

Comment: A good explanation about this topic is provided [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431978/one-solution-for-file-upload-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to handle this as,

1. Directly pass the file as,

   driver.findElement(By.id("elementId")).sendKeys("C:\path\to\your\file");
2. By using the Robot framework [click here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/IbtO_tJRVRw).

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Method for file handling:

We need :

jacob.jar  [Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/)

It will contain one jar file and 2 .dll files

AutoItX4Java.jar  [Download](https://code.google.com/p/autoitx4java/downloads/detail?name=AutoItX4Java.jar&can=2&q=)

```
public static void uploadFile(String path, String browser){

    if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){

        if(x.winWaitActive("Open", "", 10)){
            if(x.winExists("Open")){
                x.sleep(500);
                x.send(path);
                x.controlClick("Open", "", "Button2");

            }
        }

    }


    if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){

        if(x.winWaitActive("File Upload", "", 10)){
            if(x.winExists("File Upload")){
                x.sleep(500);
                x.send(path);
                x.controlClick("File Upload", "", "Button2");

            }
        }
    }

    if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("InternetExplorer")){

        if(x.winWaitActive("Choose File to Upload", "", 10)){
            if(x.winExists("Choose File to Upload")){
                x.sleep(500);
                x.send(path);
                x.controlClick("Choose File to Upload", "", "Button2");

            }
        }
    }



}


   public void test(){
       //Click on the Select button of the file upload
       uploadFile("Path", "chrome");


   }
```

Thanks... Dont click Accept or Upvote until it works for you. If it is not working for you means, please comment.. Dont Downvote...