# Selenium WebDriver click on input element to upload file freezes

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have to click on an element to upload a CSV file with Selenium WebDriver in JUnit. The input looks like this:

```
<input type="file" name="upload0" size="56" value="" id="DateiImportSchritt2Csv_upload0"/>
```

If I click on that input element an OS window opens where I have to choose my file to upload.
My problem is that if I use Selenium for clicking the input like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='wwctrl_DateiImportSchritt2Csv_upload0']/input")).click();
```

It does open the OS window, but freezes my whole test without any Exceptions. If I close the window manually, my test continues.

On another place in my code, I have to download a file. It is very similar, except it's not an input element but an anchor element (`<a>`) and it works fine there.

So how to click an input element which opens an OS window without freezing my test? Also tried `submit()`, but even the window does not open with that method.

I'm using:
Windows 7
Firefox 32.0.3
Selenium WebDriver 2.43.1
JUnit 4

**Edit:**
The whole div element looks like this:

```
<div class="group " id="wwctrl_DateiImportSchritt2Csv_upload0">
<label id="label_DateiImportSchritt2Csv_upload0" for="DateiImportSchritt2Csv_upload0">
<span>CSV-Importdatei für Ranglisten auswählen</span>
</label>
<p class="labelInfo" id="help_DateiImportSchritt2Csv_upload0">

    Bitte wählen Sie eine für den Import bestimmte Datei aus.

</p>
<input type="file" name="upload0" size="56" value="" id="DateiImportSchritt2Csv_upload0"/>
</div>
```

There is no submit button. The input is also not used for typing, you can only click on it to open a window.

Comment: may be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431978/one-solution-for-file-upload-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java

Comment: You have an input element, do you also have a 'submit' or similar button? You can typically work around the upload issye by sending the full file path to the input element using .sendKeys() and then clicking on the submit button.

Comment: Was a bit confusing for me with submit button, but also the right answer, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='wwctrl_DateiImportSchritt2Csv_upload0']/‌​input")).sendKeys("Your path");
```

Use this it works for you Good Luck...