# Test Automation. File upload Java and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

I am trying to upload a file but no succes, I found this example:

```
WebElement element = getSupport().getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='file']"));
element.sendKeys("D:/Profiles/user/workspace/copla-selenium/src/test/resources/datasets/default/test-image.jpg");
```

But I get this error:

> 2015-02-23 17:32:59 ERROR root:97 - Test failed
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus
>   element

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: There should be an `input` element responsible for the upload field.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean, in this example is like I did it: [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431978/one-solution-for-file-upload-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Comment: See the xpath used in that thread points to an `input` element - yours is pointing to an `a` element. This is probably the problem here.

Comment: I know what you mean.. I change it, now I dont get any error but it does not load the image

Comment: show part of code that U want to upload file.

Comment: Did U read Webdriver faq about file upload ???

Answer (score 1):

Are you using webdriver , If yes then sendKeys never works for webdriver.
If you want to use webdriver then try autoIt or robot class for file uploading.
Otherwise you can use remote webdriver Like this:

```
RemoteWebDriver rdriver = new RemoteWebDriver(caps);
    rdriver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
    WebElement element = rdriver.findElement(By
            .xpath(".//input[@type='file']"));
    element.sendKeys("D:/Profiles/user/workspace/copla-selenium/src/test/resources/datasets/default/test-image.jpg");
```