# Selenium Webdriver in SAP Web UI Application

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, sapui5

I'm new to selenium webdriver. I have few questions realted to selenium automation.

1. Is it possible to automate SAP CRM web UI applications.
2. Selenium wedriver supports IE11 ( Internet Explorer 11 ) browser.
3. Is it possible to automate browser test cases to check the usability. ( Not the functionality ).
4. File upload and download is possible in webdriver.
5. SAP UI5 appliation can be automated.

I will be using Selenium Wedriver with Java.

Kindly help.
Regards,
Siva

Answer (score 0):

1)  I don't see why it wouldn't be possible to automate it, unless it is written in Silverlight.

2)  Yes

3)  Kind of. Best to leave the usability tests to the acceptance testers, QA should mostly be focused on functionality, at least with automation.

4)  Yes.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29256865/upload-files-using-selenium/29257350#29257350).

5)  No.  I have had luck automating the SAP GUI with [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/), though.