# Close Flipkart open pop-up and go to main window using Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
String subWindowHandler = null;
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
}
driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler);
```

I tried it by switching to main window also. Please add valuable input or code to close the pop up.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the java Robot API by importing java.awt.Robot libraries. An example is here:

[One solution for File Upload using Java Robot API with Selenium WebDriver by Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431978/one-solution-for-file-upload-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

You can try to use it similarly to press the Esc key. Pressing Esc on flipkart website gets rid of the pop-up.

Comment: Hi Freya,
Manually by pressing Esc key it is working.
but tried with the below code but not working.

Robot robot = new Robot();
  
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);

Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi Shirsh, you have to release the key too. Try using: Robot robot = new Robot(); robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE); robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);

Comment: Hi Shirsh, please accept my post as an answer if it helped you out. And as always, please let me know if I can be of further help :)

Answer (score 0):

The pop-up which appears on Flipkart's website is a simple HTML modal. Window handle is used when a new pop-up window needs to be accessed.

To close the pop-up just click on the cross on the top right corner of the pop-up. Use [waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) to ensure that selenium finds the WebElement.

Try this:

```
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement cross = wait.until(
    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("close-icon")));
cross.click()
```

Comment: Hi Jason. Tried this but not working. did it work for you?