# failed to upload a file using selenium webdriver in Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to upload a file using selenium webd river but couldn't get this spinet code 
working

```
driver.findElement(By.id("uploadForm:j_id135")).sendKeys("path_to_file");
driver.findElement(By.name("uploadForm:j_id139")).click();
```

I also tried this suggestion:
[File Upload using Selenium WebDriver and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610256/file-upload-using-selenium-webdriver-and-java)
too bad didn't work for me

Any ideas?much appreciated

Comment: What was the error stack trace?

Comment: This seems ok (if the actual path to file is ok). Show us more, i.e. the exception thrown, maybe the two html elements.

Comment: This could be a variety of problems. Bad id/name. Browser won't recognize identifiers (IE9 does this all too often). Perhaps the element you need to interact with is hidden? Provide a stack trace to the error and we'll better be able to help you out

Answer (score 0):

You will have give the "id" of the actual input box (where the path is provided) when you manually click to upload a file (when working manually). In the Automation scenario we need to provide the correct id of that input box by using this command:

> driver.findElement(By.id("upload")).sendKeys("/path/to/the/file");

next step is off course is click the upload button.

If you are using WebDriverBackedSelenium you can use:

> selenium.type("locator", "/path/to/the/file");
>
> selenium.click("upload_button");