# IE11 is failing to click on file browser button through selenium

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Scenario:**
In my application there is file browser button. Clicking this browser the file selection windows opens. From there we select our required file and click on upload.

**Problem:**
When we are doing this on Firefox and Chrome, there is no problem. But when we are doing this through IE11 that time the file browser button is being clicked by the script, but the file selection window is not poping up. I have checked the same manually on IE11, that time no problem is happening. But script opened is not responding on that specific button. 
For ex- Through script I launched the IE and paused the script. If I am trying to click the file browser option manually on the same browser now, it would not respond with the file selection dialog window. But at the same time if I open a new browser manually and try clicking that browser option manually, then it would work.

**Web Code:**

There is a `<iframe>` object appears. Within this `iframe` the whole html page loads and under some `nested <div>` container this file browser option resides under `<input id="UploadFile" class=*** type=*** ..>` like wise.

**Selenium Code:**

```
WebElement ImportDef = driver.findElement(By.id("UploadFile"));
Thread.sleep(3000);
ImportDef.click();
```

Comment: instead of `.click()` you can set file path using `sendKeys()` as `ImportDef.sendKeys("file/to/upload")`..

Comment: This click is for clicking the file browse button on the webpage. If the file selection dialog doesn't popup, how can I upload /set path for a file?? My prob is not about uploading the file. My problem is that the file selection dialog is not appearing on the active screen when we are executing on IE11

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610256/file-upload-using-selenium-webdriver-and-java

Comment: You should not handle upload button, but input field instead

Comment: @SaurabhGaur: I have seen the above link. They looks like similar but not. First:In that problem it was not working on both Firefox and IE11, for me it isnot working only for IE. Second: In that problem after clicking browse option the selection window was at least opening, for me it is not. Still I would like to try that one. Lets see

Comment: Ok means your problem is why is upload window not open. Rigth??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur: Yes, you are correct. That is also for IE11

Comment: So when are you going to click there is any exception??

Comment: @Andersson: There is no such input field. When I click the browser option, it directly opens the file selection window. This is the scenario.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur :No. No such exception is there. Because actually the script keeps waiting to pop up the file selection window. After a certain time of waiting it gets time out.

Comment: Could you share your website URL??

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to do so. As it is  copy right content, you need credentials to access.Also, I am not authorize to share any internal code. I know sharing the code could be more easy for you all, bt not possible.

Comment: @RoyCode, `<input id="UploadFile" class=*** type=*** ..>` this is the target input field. You should send local path to file as string to this input element

Comment: @Andersson: Understood your point.Let me try and share the outcome