# Handle file upload with Selenium Server Standalone

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-server

I try to execute testsuite on a remote host with use of `Selenium Standalone Server`. It should upload a file. I use code below to handle file uploads:

```
FileBrowserDialogHandler fileBrowserDialogHandler = new FileBrowserDialogHandler();
fileBrowserDialogHandler.fileUploadDialog(fileSource);
```

It doesn't work when I execute it remotely, because it is not able to open file chooser window. 
Input field looks like this on webpage:

> <input type="text" id="file-path">

I replaced current solution with `WebElement` based one to avoid graphical window, but it doesn't work.

```
WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(By.id("filepathelement"));
fileInput.sendKeys(filepath);
```

Input type is not file, so code below is not working:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("myUploadElement")).sendKeys("<absolutePathToMyFile>");
```

Comment: It's not supposed to open the file chooser window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload file using Selenium WebDriver in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896685/how-to-upload-file-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java)

Comment: @JeffC : It is not a duplicate, because type of field is different and that solution isn't works in this case.

Comment: Please post a link to the page. I'm guessing there's an input of type file on the page somewhere, hidden or otherwise, that you can use.

Comment: Input type is not file??then what type u want to upload

Comment: @iamsankalp89, @JeffC : It uses `JavaScript` onchange method, like this:
`document.getElementById('file-path').value = this.value.split('\\')[this.value.split('\\').length-1];`

Comment: Can you post rest of the JavaScript code? Or is the url publicly available for testing?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Above posted is the only JS, that I see on field.

Comment: Can't help without getting complete page

Comment: @plaidshirt, in the html snippet `id` value is different and it is different in your code which does the upload.

Comment: Please post the code of the test.

Comment: @TarunLalwani: It is really similar to the form on this site:(Please specify a file, or a set of files) http://jkorpela.fi/forms/file.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file(s) in question should be available on the machine (be it local or remote server) that your program is running on, for example, in your /resources directory

On your local machine, this should work.

```
chooseFileElement.waitForVisible().type("/file/path/filename.jpg");
clickButton("Attach File");
```

On Remote Server however, you need to associate a new instance of LocalFileDetector to the `<input type=file>` element.

```
LocalFileDetector detector = new LocalFileDetector();
File localFile = detector.getLocalFile("/file/path/filename.jpg");
RemoteWebElement input = (RemoteWebElement) myDriver().findElement(By.id("fileUpload"));
input.setFileDetector(detector);
input.sendKeys(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
clickButton("Attach File");
```

Answer (score 5):

**Upload a file using Java `Selenium: sendKeys()` or [`Robot Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html).**

This method is to Set the specified file-path to the ClipBoard.

1. Copy data to ClipBoard as.

   - WIN [ <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + C ]
   - MAC [ <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>  + C ] - way to [`tell full Path of file`](https://superuser.com/questions/371513/how-to-tell-full-path-of-file-on-mac).

---

```
public static void setClipboardData(String filePath) {
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection( filePath );
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
}
```

---

2. Locate the file on Finder Window and press `OK` to select the file.

   - WIN [ <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + V ]
   - MAC

     - "[**`Go To Folder`**](http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/31/go-to-folder-useful-mac-os-x-keyboard-shortcut/)" - <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>  + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + G.
     - Paste -  <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>  + V and
     - press `OK` to open it.

---

```
enum Action {
    WIN, MAC, LINUX, SEND_KEYS;
}
public static boolean FileUpload(String locator, String filePath, Action type) {
    WebDriverWait explicitWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    WebElement element = explicitWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable( By.xpath(locator) ));
    if( type == Action.SEND_KEYS ) {
        element.sendKeys( filePath );
        return true;
    } else {
        try {
            element.click();

            Thread.sleep( 1000 * 5 );

            setClipboardData(filePath);

            Robot robot = new Robot();
            if( type == Action.MAC ) { // Apple's Unix-based operating system.

                // “Go To Folder” on Mac - Hit Command+Shift+G on a Finder window.
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_G);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_G);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);

                // Paste the clipBoard content - Command ⌘ + V.
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);

                // Press Enter (GO - To bring up the file.)
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                return true;
            } else if ( type == Action.WIN || type == Action.LINUX ) { // Ctrl + V to paste the content.

                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            }

            robot.delay( 1000 * 4 );

            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            return true;
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

File Upload Test **:-** You can find [`fileUploadBytes.html`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_files.asp) file by clicking on [`Try it Yourself`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_fileupload_files).

```
public static void uploadTest( RemoteWebDriver driver ) throws Exception {
    //driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
    String baseUrl = "file:///D:/fileUploadBytes.html";
    driver.get( baseUrl );
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    FileUpload("//input[1]", "D:\\log.txt", Action.SEND_KEYS);

    Thread.sleep( 1000 * 10 );

    FileUpload("//input[1]", "D:\\DB_SQL.txt", Action.WIN);

    Thread.sleep( 1000 * 10 );

    driver.quit();
}
```

---

For more information see [`my post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46447150/5081877).