# Uploading a file using Selenium Webdriver and Java

Tags: java, selenium, button, webdriver, selenide

I'm trying to upload a file using Selenium Webdriver and Java. I use sendKeys method on WebElement and this not working for me. I tried a lot of solution for example from this [File Upload using Selenium WebDriver and Java Robot Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610256/file-upload-using-selenium-webdriver-and-java-robot-class) and also nothing.

Code with button:

```
<div class="button_to_upload" xpath="1">
    <span tabindex="0" class="upload" role="button">
        <input type="file" style="display: none;">
        <button class="any_class_button" type="button" style="min-width: 50px;">
            <span class="icon">
            </span><span style="">Upload something</span>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to upload file using WebDriver is to set the text value of  to file path. Something like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.ByXpath("//input[@type = 'file']")).sendKeys(filePath);
```